# How to Declar Member Function with both `requires` and `-> return_type`

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I want to write a class template, which:

- `A<float>` have just a member variable `val`;
- `A<int>` have a member variable `val` and a member function `make_unsigned` (return `unsigned`).

I want to explicitly state the return value of `make_unsigned`. Here is my code.

```
#include <concepts>

template<typename T> struct A
{
    T val;
    std::make_unsigned_t<T> make_unsigned() requires std::signed_integral<T>
    {
        return static_cast<std::make_unsigned<T>::type>(val);
    }
};


int main()
{
    A<float> val;
    return 0;
}
```

Also I have tried `auto make_unsigned() requires std::signed_integral<T> -> std::make_unsigned_t<T>` and `auto make_unsigned() -> std::make_unsigned_t<T> requires std::signed_integral<T>`, but all of them cannot be compiled. It complains:

```
~ LANG=C g++ main.cpp -std=c++20 -o main
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/move.h:57,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/utility:70,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/array:38,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct std::make_unsigned<float>’:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits:1965:11:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Tp> using make_unsigned_t = typename std::make_unsigned::type [with _Tp = float]’
main.cpp:8:29:   required from ‘struct A<float>’
main.cpp:17:14:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits:1826:62: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::__make_unsigned_selector<float, false, false>’
 1826 |     { typedef typename __make_unsigned_selector<_Tp>::__type type; };
      |                                                              ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits:1733:11: note: declaration of ‘class std::__make_unsigned_selector<float, false, false>’
 1733 |     class __make_unsigned_selector;
```

Or:

```
~ LANG=C g++ main.cpp -std=c++20 -o main
main.cpp:8:59: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
    8 |     auto make_unsigned() requires std::signed_integral<T> -> std::make_unsigned_t<T>
      |                                                           ^~
main.cpp:8:62: error: invalid use of ‘using make_unsigned_t = typename std::make_unsigned<_Tp>::type’
    8 |     auto make_unsigned() requires std::signed_integral<T> -> std::make_unsigned_t<T>
      |                                                              ^~~
cc1plus: error: expression must be enclosed in parenthese
```

Or:

```
~ LANG=C g++ main.cpp -std=c++20 -o main
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/move.h:57,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/utility:70,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/array:38,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct std::make_unsigned<float>’:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits:1965:11:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Tp> using make_unsigned_t = typename std::make_unsigned::type [with _Tp = float]’
main.cpp:8:10:   required from ‘struct A<float>’
main.cpp:17:14:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits:1826:62: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::__make_unsigned_selector<float, false, false>’
 1826 |     { typedef typename __make_unsigned_selector<_Tp>::__type type; };
      |                                                              ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits:1733:11: note: declaration of ‘class std::__make_unsigned_selector<float, false, false>’
 1733 |     class __make_unsigned_selector;
```

How can I do it?

Comment: It's `-> ReturnType requires ...`, but the issue here seems to be that the requires expression does not prevent the return type from being instantiated, and `std::make_unsigned` requires that the `T` be integral ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned ). Any reason not to use return type deduction? I know you said you want to be explicit, but that seems like the easiest fix?

Comment: @Justin No reason, it's just I like to explicitly write out the return type. Yes, implicit is the easiest fix.

Comment: @ThePhilomath, why should T be returned? It would be semantically wrong and also in terms of range conservation. Did I miss something?

Comment: @陈浩南, for your case here, I'd prefer class template specialization simply to emphasize the type distinction but if you want to do it your way, you could further apply 'require' for your return type, making the non-integral value case a false type for instance, naming it tryMakeUnsigned<T> for instance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::make_unsigned` is not SFINAE friendly, so you have to

- don't be explicit on return type, use `auto`/`decltype(auto)`:

  ```
  auto make_unsigned() requires std::signed_integral<T>
  {
      return static_cast<std::make_unsigned<T>::type>(val);
  }
  ```
- add a "friendly" trait (a trait which doesn't make the program ill-formed with invalid type), and additionally use a return type (as function is not template, no SFINAE here):

  ```
  template <typename T>
  struct make_unsigned_or_self
  {
      using type = T;    
  };
  template <typename T>
  using make_unsigned_or_self_t = typename make_unsigned_or_self<T>::type;

  template <std::signed_integral T>
  struct make_unsigned_or_self<T>
  {
       using type = std::make_unsigned_t<T>;
  };
  ```

  and then

  ```
  make_unsigned_or_self_t<T> make_unsigned() requires std::signed_integral<T>
  {
      return static_cast<std::make_unsigned<T>::type>(val);
  }
  ```

  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56685f42c7516536)